# Convert a String into a List of string

Tags: apex, list

How can I convert a String of that type : 
`123, 456, 789`

into a `List<String>` ? So I can access to the value 123 for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use split method. this method will split the string using provided regex.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

```
String str = '123, 456, 789';
List<String> lstString = str.split(',');
System.debug('-----lstString----'+lstString);
```